# Using A Crosstab On A Report

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, crosstab, ms-access-2016

I have a crosstab query set to return the inputs for each recipe in my database (see picture). I'd like to know how to set up my crosstab query with fixed column headings (15 to be exact) so that I can use this query on a form. I have found a little help from fmsinc.com located [HERE](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html). However, I do not know how to change the column heading of my WHERE clause so that it matches my IN clause. When I write "IN (1,2,3)" in SQL the columns show in the resulting columns, but there are no values because 1 does not equal "A455AJ" (like in the picture).

Ideally, I would like help/advice on how to (1) create fixed columns and (2) add the crosstab query to a report. I've been given [THIS](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1976652) link but I believe it assumes the reader knows how to display a crosstab query on a report already and I don't.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the `IN` clause to *your* columns. The linked article uses `1,2,3...` due to their specific data. Therefore, simply open the SQL view of your query and add your needed 15 values.

```
TRANSFORM ...
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
PIVOT ...
IN ('A455AJ', 'A456AK', ...)
```

Do note, this `IN()` clause serves as both a filter and order of columns. Items can be quoted or not.

---

Alternatively, if you need to subset columns by form controls, use `IN` inside a `WHERE` clause condition of a derived table subquery -allowable in crosstab queries.

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 1] TEXT(255),
           [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 2] TEXT(255),
           ...;
TRANSFORM ...
SELECT ...
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE col_item IN ([Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 1], 
                      [Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 2],
                      ...)
  ) As sub
GROUP BY ...
PIVOT ...
```

Comment: How do I get the IN Clause to change when the user types in a different recipe, like 'A064AL'? I tried IN ([Forms]![frm_BulkComparison_Select]![Item 1], etc...) but the field simply got named that tag and the value didn't populate.

Comment: That seems to be a different question that your posting. You will need to build a query dynamically with code such as with [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845522.aspx) in VBA.

Comment: While this is not the answer I'm looking for, Parfait did answer the question. I should have worded it better. Thank you for the assist.

Comment: Actually @Lando, there might be a way by using `IN` inside a `WHERE` clause and not `PIVOT` clause. See extended answer. Be sure to add `PARAMETERS` clause (closed with semicolon) above `TRANSFORM`.